# REGEXP_CONTAINS : is there any particular order

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it the correct order to get the output:Do I need to change the order.

```
(case
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(place, '(?i)BUS') THEN "BUS"
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(place, '(?i)SAV') THEN "SAV"
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(place, '(?i)CC')  THEN "CC" 
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(place, '(?i)TRA') THEN "TR" 
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(place, '(?i)HL')  THEN "HL"
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(place, '(?i)BR')  THEN "BR" 
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(place, '(?i)INS') THEN "INS"
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(place, '(?i)INV') THEN "INV"
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(place, '(?i)BRA') THEN "BR"
 end) as pf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(place, '(\w+)(BR|INV|INS|BR|HL|TRA|CC|SAV|BUS$)', '\\2')
```

EDIT: for TRA=TR

```
(\w+)(BR|INV|INS|BR|HL|TR|CC|SAV|BUS)((?<=TR)A?)$
```

Comment: But I have one BRA=BR. what to do for this one? and also TRA=TR

Comment: what do you want to extract from TRA=TR?

Comment: if there is TRA, then I will present it as TR.

Comment: please check my edit